# Change background color in cycles when rendering only diffuse

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm doing flat color diffuse-only renders as described here:

[Rendering Diffuse Color pass in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/rendering-diffuse-color-pass-in-cycles)

This (understandably) always renders the background as black.

What nodes do I need to hook up if I want the world background color to show behind the diffuse-only rendered objects?

Comment: Probably use the environment of Render Layers and combine it with the output with a alpha over node

Comment: [Q: *Use multiple HDRIs*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris) or [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66684/30849)